# How to import outlook express mails into thunderbird mail client?

Tags: thunderbird

We are in the process of converting all our windows systems into ubuntu. Is there a way to import outlook express mails into thunderbird in Ubuntu?

Comment: The easiest way is to install Thunderbird on your Windows Machine and transfer your email there see [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_.pst_files) and [here](http://www.twistermc.com/1376/outlook-thunderbird/).  You can then backup your email and restore it on your Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2):

Install Thunderbird on a windows machine, and go to Tools menu, choose Tools --> import.  When the window opens choose mail, and then pick outlook express.  Repeat for other items.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: When importing into a Thunderbird on Windows, it is important to make sure that the "bittyness" of Outlook and Thunderbird matches. Trying to import from a 32-bit Outlook into a 64-bit will result in a `Profile not found` error. See [this SO post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440375/1118505).